# Group images that contains image overlay to the centre of the page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center a group (a table with 3x3) of pictures to the center of the webpage, I manage to do it before adding image overlay to it. But since I added image overlay, the images are appearing on top left of the webpage. How do i group them and center them, also how am I supposed to get the image location so that when I set the image overlay, it goes to the specific picture as each picture will have different image overlay text.

CSS

```
.container {
   position: relative;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
}

.image {
   display: block;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
 }

 .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .5s ease;

 }

 .container:hover .overlay {
      opacity: 1;
 }

.text {
   color: red;
   font-size: 20px;
   font-weight: bold;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 }
```

HTML

```
<div style="text-align:center">
 <div class="container">
 <img src="wheel1.jpg" class="image">
    <div class="overlay">
        <div class="text">Hello World</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<img src="wheels2.jpg" class="image">
    <div class="overlay">
        <div class="text">Hello World</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<img src="wheel3.jpg" class="image"">
    <div class="overlay">
        <div class="text">Hello World</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could center it using `flexbox`. Change your main div

```
<div style="text-align-center;">
     ......
</div>
```

to

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;align-items: center;">
    .....
</div>
```

And it should work.

```css
.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
   position: relative;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
}

.image {
   display: block;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   border: 1px solid red;
 }

 .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .5s ease;

 }

 .container:hover .overlay {
      opacity: 1;
 }

.text {
   color: red;
   font-size: 20px;
   font-weight: bold;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="container">
   <div class="image"></div>
      <div class="overlay">
          <div class="text">Hello World</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="container">
  <div class="image"></div>
      <div class="overlay">
          <div class="text">Hello World</div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
  <div class="image"></div>
      <div class="overlay">
          <div class="text">Hello World</div>
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

[Here is the fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/34tu0xyt/1/)

Comment: Yep it did work, images are now centre, however I wanted a 3x3 table, so 3 images each row, at the moment im getting 1 image under another. Before adding image overlay they were working fine, cant find the error now. I tried changing flex-direction to "row" and now the 3 images is in a row however they are back to the top left again.

Comment: @Luke Add `justify-content: center` and `flex-direction: row`. See updated answer

Comment: Yeah I figured flex-direction: row was the right one. thanks for the help its working now.

Comment: @Luke Glad I could help. You can accept the answer if someone else has the same problem.

Comment: this is my second time asking a question, i normaly just browse for answer, sorry for asking this, but how do i accept the answer? cant seem to find any button that does that.

Comment: @Luke Below up and down arrows you have check icon, just click on it. Here is the link [How to accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)